# Создать скриншот библиотекой PHP-FFMpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

Несколько часов разбираюсь с библиотекой https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg
Не могу разобраться как делать скриншоты с заданным размером кадров т.е. в 1 изображении несколько небольших снимков видео.
Первые этап создать снимки видео.
Код ниже генерирует 10 кадров в секунду вместо якобы заданного FRAMERATE_EVERY_60SEC (каждые 60 секунд).

```
$video
    ->filters()
    ->extractMultipleFrames(FFMpeg\Filters\Video\ExtractMultipleFramesFilter::FRAMERATE_EVERY_60SEC, '/path/to/destination/folder/')
    ->synchronize();

$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), '/path/to/new/file');
```

А этот работает, но не знаю как изменить размер кадров, генерируются полно размерные.

```
    $video = $ffmpeg->open($video_file);
    $interval = 200; // Пример
    for($i=0; $i < 12; $i++)
    {
        $img = .jpg';
        $frame = $video->frame(\FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds($interval * $i));
        $frame->save($img);
        $result[] = $img;
    }
```

Второй этап склеить все кадры в 1 изображение. Как это сделать тоже не знаю.
Может кто нибудь помочь в этом вопросе?